# How to use AngularJS $scope?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a paragraph and a counter. I want to update the counter when someone clicks on the paragraph using AngularJS. I wrote the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<p>Click on this paragraph.</p>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<h2>{{ count }}</h2>
</div>
<script>
var $ang;
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $ang=$scope;
    $ang.count=10;
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
        console.log("The paragraph was clicked.");
        $ang.count=$ang.count-1;
    });
});
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

But it's not working. I guess I'am using `$scope` in a wrong way but I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Why you have kept `p` outside the angular app? What is your requirement?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You had several errors in your code. I've refactored it a bit. Make sure to use **ng-app** and **ng-controller** properly. Do not use **jquery** in combination with angular. You can observe scope changes with the **$watch** function - this method is expensive in terms of computation and should not be overused.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <p ng-click="onClick()">Click on this paragraph.</p>

    <h2>{{ count }}</h2>
</div>

</div>
<script>


angular
    .module('myApp', ['ng'])

    .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.count = 10
        $scope.onClick = function () {
            $scope.count--
        }

        // this is how you can observe state
        // changes outside of event handlers
        $scope.$watch('count', function(newValue, oldValue) {
            console.log("The paragraph was clicked.")
        })
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you need a watch here?

Comment: @sisyphus You don't really need it. It's there for demonstration purposes only - to show the author how to observe **state** changes outside of event handlers.

Comment: You say "Do not use jQuery" but you load it as ressource? Why?

Comment: @MK . Okay. I am glad we agree a watch is not at all needed in this case.

Comment: @lin it is a copy paste from authors snippet. If he thinks that he needs jquery, it's not up to me to completely remove it.

Comment: @sisyphus absolutely

Answer (score 1):

[**Don't mix angular with jQuery!**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Rather follow angular way of doing it, Wrap all things in angular context just by moving `ng-app` & `ng-controller` directive on body and have and then place `ng-click` on `p` tag and do your desired task there

**Markup**

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <p ng-click="increamentCount()">Click on this paragraph.</p>
   <div>
       <h2>{{ count }}</h2>
   </div>
<body>
```

**Code**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.count = 10;
    $scope.increamentCount = function(){
      $scope.count = $scope.count + 1;
    }
});
```

[**Demo Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/VNxfhYTgAl5M0eo88gBa?p=preview)

Comment: Why not, its called `jAngQuelarry`. Its like mixing soil with air and drink it.

Comment: @lin Lol, that's great word *jAngQuelarry*, why you think that?

Comment: =) I'am just bored of all the jQuery newbies who don't know how angular is used in the right way. They all try to mix jQuery with angular. -> jAngQuelarry.

Comment: Lol.. even I get bored so I do link that awesome answer which has covered all aspects. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>   

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<p ng-click="click()">Click on this paragraph.</p>
<h2>{{ count }}</h2>
</div>
<script>
var $ang;
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.count = 10;
    $scope.click = function(){
         $scope.count=$scope.count-1;
    }
});
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, you fixed it. Gratulations.